# How to copy each row in excel and paste it under the copied row

Tags: excel

I am looking for a way to copy each row in a sheet and paste it under the original row.

CURRENTLY:

```
1 | abc | def
2 | ghi | jkl
3 | mno | pqr
```

WHAT I AIM TO DO:

```
1 | abc | def
2 | abc | def
3 | ghi | jkl
4 | ghi | jkl
5 | mno | pqr
6 | mno | pqr
```

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: So you got an Excel-Sheet and want for each line to insert the same line below?

Comment: that is correct yes, copy each line, and paste it beneath the ogirinal, so row 1 goes to row 2 while keeping row 1 in place, each row will be duplicated beneath itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method which does not require fancy formulas or macros/VBA.  Just copy the entire top block, in this case three rows, and then paste immediately underneath.  Then sort by the first ID column, which will group the original row with its copy.  Finally, generate a new ID sequence down all rows starting with one at the top.  As a series of steps:

1. Copy original data and paste underneath
2. Sort new + copy data on the number ID column
3. Generate a new ID column starting with 1 at the first row

Comment: Thanks, your logic made this a very simple solution to what was at first a complicated problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do it like this:

1. Copy whole table to another sheet
2. Create an id column for both table
3. Give odd id number for the main table and give even id number for the copied table
4. Copy and paste copied table to main table and sort main table by id and then remove id column and delete copied sheet.

Answer (score 0):

With vba assuming no gaps in range

```
Option Explicit

Sub Testing()

Dim targetRange As Range
Dim sourceData()

With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    sourceData = .Value2
    Set targetRange = .Resize(.Rows.Count * 2, .Columns.Count)

End With

Dim currValue As Long
Dim counter As Long
counter = 1

For currValue = LBound(sourceData, 1) To UBound(sourceData, 1)

    targetRange.Cells(counter, 1).Resize(2, UBound(sourceData, 2)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(sourceData, currValue, 0)
    counter = counter + 2

Next currValue

End Sub
```

**Source data in A1:B3**

[image: Start layout]